# What is the subset of {{Ø}}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My textbook says:

{Ø} is not a subset of {{Ø}} since the only element of {Ø} is Ø and the only element of {{Ø}} is {Ø},
so the element of {Ø} is not an element of {{Ø}}.

I think it might be {{Ø}}

Comment: The only subsets of a singleton set $A = \{a\}$ are $A$ and $\emptyset$

Answer (score 3):

First, let me say that asking for "the subset" is usually a wrong question to ask, because sets usually have more than one subset.

A set that includes only one element is a **singleton**. Singletons always have 2 subsets -- the empty set $\emptyset$ and the entire set itself.

For example the set $\{a\}$ has two subsets: $\emptyset$ and $\{a\}$.

Your example is a singleton too: the only element of the set is $\{\emptyset\}$. Do not mind the fact that this element itself is a set with another element in it. Just pretend it is $a$ as in the example above. Can you now list all the subsets of $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ ?

Comment: Are all the subsets of {{∅}}, Ø and {{Ø}}?